# How can I switch items using mouse buttons instead of the scroll wheel?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mouse

My mouse (a [Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 5000](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Wireless-Laser-Mouse-5000/dp/B000F5FRGC)) has smooth scroll (I can't turn it off) which means using the mouse wheel to change items is not ideal, sometimes it doesn't register the wheel turn, other times it registers it as 3.

Is there any way to change the item switch buttons to something else? Ideally mouse 4 and 5 (the side buttons).

Comment: I know it's not terribly useful for the right half of your inventory, but if you weren't aware, 1-0 select the corresponding slots in your inventory

Comment: @Dave Yes I knew that, it's just hard to select the right one without looking away, and if you need to switch quickly it takes too long. Also it's only 1-9.

Comment: @Roman I assumed you would, but it was worth asking.  If you can't directly configure minecraft, you may look into some tools to help you remap your mouse buttons.  You could then create a batch file to open minecraft and some remapping script together.  It's not ideal, but probably possible

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's any way within Minecraft to configure it – you'll have to look for third party solutions to remap `Mouse 5` & `Mouse 6` to `scroll up` & `scroll down`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to remap the scroll wheel *within* Minecraft, so I think your best bet is to look for third-party tools that will remap your mouse keys for you. After a quick Google search, I found [**X-Mouse Button Control**](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) for Windows, and [**USB Overdrive**](http://usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) for Mac.

Looking at screenshots of both programs, they both allow you to remap mouse buttons as `mouse wheel up {MWUP}` and `mouse wheel down {MWDN}`, which is perfect for item-switching in Minecraft.

---

**X-Mouse**:
[image: X-Mouse Button Control]

**USB Overdrive**:
[image: USB Overdrive]

Comment: At first I thought this was similar to Microsoft Mouse, but this has way more functionality!

Comment: Another option for windows is [EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.org/).  I use it for my HTPC, since it automatically switches profiles based on the active application.

Comment: I know this is 9 years old... But I'm currently using x-mouse but I can't map the program to minecraft since the exe opens the launcher and the launcher opens a new window for the game... Any ideas?